# How is a decompiler able to recognize a compiled constant?

Tags: c#, decompiling, compile-time-constant, ilspy

I am using ILSpy to decompile the assemblies of .Net and look into the code. As I was browsing the code of `System.Windows.Vector.AngleBetween(Vector, Vector)` in `WindowsBase.dll`, I stumbled across something bizarre.

This is the full code of the function:

```
public static double AngleBetween(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
{
    double y = vector1._x * vector2._y - vector2._x * vector1._y;
    double x = vector1._x * vector2._x + vector1._y * vector2._y;
    return Math.Atan2(y, x) * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

Apparently ILSpy could recognize `Math.PI`, which is a constant.

This is what [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants) says about constants in C#:

> In fact, when the compiler encounters a constant identifier in C# source code, it substitutes the literal value directly into the intermediate language (IL) code that it produces.

Based on this, what ILSpy did seems impossible.

Note: this behavior is present even if the "Use variable names from debug symbols, if available" and "Show info from debug symbols, if available"
 options are unchecked in the settings.

Comment: Possibly ILSpy just knows the value of common constants like `Math.PI` when it sees them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in this [ILSpy issue](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/issues/517) and the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/pull/1350/files/9e71e7fe09ba8a60a019f72a054bcc9cbd8cecd5), this was specifically implemented (hardcoded) for well-known values such as `Math.PI`.

From the GitHub issue:

> I suppose to calculate pi coefficient by following way: 
>   `c = Math.PI / constant`. If we getting "good" value (equal exactly to 1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 1/180 and so on), we simply replacing it with symbolic expression (Math.PI, Math.PI * 2, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 180 and so on).

Comment: How then the ILSpy is able to recognize not well known constants ?

Comment: Do you have an example of  a non-well-known constant that it recognizes?

Comment: @DmytroMukalov It can probably recognize non-well-known constants from the debug symbols (PDB files), but I haven't tested this.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov I just tested, and it didn't recognize `Math.PI * 254.543`, even with 'use debug symbols' on

Answer (score 0):

A quick test in LINQPad shows some differences in the IL code generated (PI constant value copied from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pi?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Source:

```
void Main()
{
    double a = Math.PI;
    double b = 3.14159265358979;
}
```

---

IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.r8      18 2D 44 54 FB 21 09 40 
IL_000A:  stloc.0     // a
IL_000B:  ldc.r8      11 2D 44 54 FB 21 09 40 
IL_0014:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0015:  ret
```

There does seem to be a subtle difference in the IL code generated between the constant and the literal values, but I'm not sure exactly what it means yet.

---

The above values from the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pi?view=netframework-4.7.2) seem to contradict information from the [.NET Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,fa5fd1f4e5f6f911,references) (See comments).  With adjusted code from the source, the IL is identical.

Source:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = Math.PI;
    var b = 3.14159265358979323846;
}
```

IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.r8      18 2D 44 54 FB 21 09 40 
IL_000A:  stloc.0     // a
IL_000B:  ldc.r8      18 2D 44 54 FB 21 09 40 
IL_0014:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0015:  ret
```

---

As an aside, it looks like there is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/2043) to address the documentation / source code inconsistency.

Comment: `Math.PI` is definitely a const, it's declaration: `public const double PI = 3.1415926535897931;`

Comment: I was just going by the MSDN documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pi?view=netframework-4.7.2, which lists it as a field.

Comment: The value you give is also different from the value in the linked documentation.

Comment: According to the [C# Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,fa5fd1f4e5f6f911,references), you are correct. it is declared as a constant.  I will adjust my answer.